# A violation of Florida Statute 790.15

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, florida

If a group of friends goes out several miles into Everglades National Park and does some target shooting. Are they violating [Florida Statute 790.15](http://flsenate.gov/Laws/Statutes/2013/790.15)?

- What about if they were on any "Public" land that is NOT a national park?
- What about if they were on "Private" land?

Comment: The "wilderness" means nothing. Who owns the land? Federal? State? BLM? Private?

Comment: If they're in a _National Park_, isn't this automatically a public place?

Comment: @cHao National parks have different regulations.

Comment: Google: https://www.nps.gov/ever/learn/management/lawsandpolicies.htm

Comment: Not sure why the down vote. I'm asking a valid legal question that has proper multipart answer.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch This comment isn't helpful and is not in the spirit of the site being as most questions can be googled unless you provide that as source for an answer.

Comment: @DigitalFire It's not helpful and not in the spirit of the site to ask a question without first doing some research and putting some thought into your question. That's why I had to ask you what you meant about "wilderness" and if this was public or private land and who is the administrator of that public land.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I modified the question the first time you mentioned the lack of detail. I have properly researched the question and if you check my post history as of the past couple day. Most of my question have been regarding Florida statue 790 and my reading of information of said statue. This one in particular is regarding 790.15. I'm well aware of the answer prior to even asking the question. As it stands, there is more than enough information and detail to fall as a valid question.

Comment: @DigitalFire From your structure of your question, it doesn't appear that you are well aware of the answer prior to asking the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key portion of the statute states that it applies to the discharge of a firearm:

> **in any public place** or **on the right-of-way of any paved public road,
>   highway, or street,** who knowingly discharges any firearm **over the
>   right-of-way of any paved public road, highway, or street** or **over any
>   occupied premises,** or who recklessly or negligently discharges a
>   firearm **outdoors on any property used primarily as the site of a
>   dwelling** as defined in s. 776.013 or **zoned exclusively for residential
>   use** commits a misdemeanor of the first degree, punishable as provided
>   in s. 775.082 or s. 775.083. This section does not apply to a person
>   lawfully defending life or property or performing official duties
>   requiring the discharge of a firearm or to a person discharging a
>   firearm on public roads or properties expressly approved for hunting
>   by the Fish and Wildlife Conservation Commission or Florida Forest
>   Service.

Assuming that the permitted hunting approval exception does not apply in all cases, it would not be directly applicable in a federal park (where federal courts probably have exclusive jurisdiction), although there is probably an assimilative crimes act that adopts state law as a federal criminal offense in cases not provided for by express federal statutes that would apply as if it were state land.

So, you can't discharge a firearm "in any public place", over a paved road, over an occupied building, on a residential lot, or in a residential lot (other subsections limit firing guns from our vehicle).

It appears that "in a public place" is a question of fact, but that would not be synonymous with, land owned by the government. Instead, it would be in places where members of the public gather such as courtyards, malls, plazas, parking lots and the like. Some places in Everglades National Park or public lands would be "in a public place", but that wouldn't necessarily apply to all places on government owned land. A secluded meadow or bare place in the marsh might not be "in a public place."

Private land would usually not be "a public place" although a mall or amusement park or concert venue or other place open to the public but privately owned probably would be "a public place."

A paved private road would probably be covered, as would any residentially zoned land and any land in the curtilage of a home or occupied building.

But, otherwise, shooting on private land (not from a vehicle) would be permitted whether it was vacant land, farm land, industrial property, or commercial property without occupied structures or paved roads (e.g. warehouses or storage sheds).

Comment: Pretty spot on with a minor exception, 'So, you can't discharge a firearm "in any public place", over a "paved public road", over an occupied building, on a residential lot, or in a residential lot (other subsections limit firing guns from our vehicle).' Here is an article about a Florida man who built a backyard, out door gun range in a residential lot. https://www.nbcnews.com/video/florida-mans-backyard-gun-range-is-legal-393117251777

Comment: I don't normally use a computer in a place that I can listen to audio. Who says it is legal? The fact that a guy says what he is doing is legal doesn't make it so, nor does the fact that the local law enforcement agency declines to enforce a criminal statutes.

Comment: I don't disagree with you. Just giving an instance of an exception. There are several of these type of situations around Florida. So it is not as a singular exception.

Comment: @DigitalFire I have little doubt that the neighbors could obtain an injunction from a court in a civil action prohibiting this conduct on threat of incarceration for contempt of court if he violated the court order. It looks like irresponsible news reporting to me. The fact that the law is violated and no one does something about it doesn't mean something is legal.

Comment: Here is another article about the same guy in a better format; https://news.vice.com/article/a-florida-man-turned-his-front-yard-into-a-shooting-range-and-thats-perfectly-legal

Comment: @DigitalFire I imagined two possibilities. First, the police are wrong. Second, that in response to incidents like this the residential zoning clause was added to the law. The legislative history of the law indicates that the last time that the statute was amended was in 2012 and that story is from 2015, so the most likely answer is that the police are wrong. Police are not a reliable source for legal advice.

Comment: I found a recent change to the law that indeed made it illegal (SB130, Feb 2016?). So I believe up until then it was legal.

Comment: The new bill is at https://www.flsenate.gov/Session/Bill/2016/130/BillText/er/PDF and its language suggests a third possibility which is that the property described in the video and vice article was not zoned as exclusively residential even though, in fact, only residential properties were constructed there. Perhaps it was part of a multi-use PUD or something like that.

Comment: There was a similar incident with an individual in Big Pine Key which I believe was in a residential zone. Ill see if I can pull up info on that one.

Comment: http://www.miamiherald.com/news/local/community/florida-keys/article45784400.html